# Webkit (Chrome/Safari) only AJAX response error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, webkit

I am returning some JSON from an AJAX request to a simple PHP script. Everything works fine with IE & Firefox, but Chrome does not like the response at all. Basically, I am getting the JSON back on success, but this is accompanied by an error and so the script fails.

The jQuery is pretty straigt-forward (I have removed most of the callback as it is irrelevant to the problem - the script fails with or without it):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {'cache-control': 'no-cache'},
    cache: false,
    url: 'ajax/request.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(a){
        $.each(a, function(b, c){
            var d = $.map(c, function(e){
                return e;
            });

            -- do stuff with results --

        });
    },
    error: function(a, b, c){
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
     }
});
```

The PHP script looks something like this (I have an object which does a very basic query, and the results are encoded to JSON format):

```
$gallery = new gallery;
$gallery_json = $gallery->select_all($number);
echo json_encode($gallery_json);
```

The console (only with webkit) shows "readyState: 4" and "status: 200", etc. and continues with the following errors:

```
parsererror

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input {stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input↵    at Object…om/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js:4:25897)", message: "Unexpected end of input"}
message: "Unexpected end of input"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input↵    at Object.parse (native)↵    at m.parseJSON (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js:4:15739)↵    at Pc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js:4:18120)↵    at x (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js:4:21525)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.m.ajaxTransport.send.b (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js:4:25897)"
get stack: function () { [native code] }
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""
prototype: StackTraceGetter
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
set stack: function () { [native code] }
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: StackTraceSetter
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
__proto__: Error
constructor: function SyntaxError() { [native code] }
name: "SyntaxError"
stack: undefined
get stack: function () { [native code] }
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""
prototype: StackTraceGetter
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
set stack: function () { [native code] }
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: StackTraceSetter
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
__proto__: d
```

(Apologies for the messed up spacing)

The JSON comes back correctly with other browsers, so I am confident that there is not a problem with the query itself and no PHP errors are being reported. Also, if a try to access some of the contents of the returned JSON (for example alerting some part of "var d", as in "alert(d[2]);" somewhere in the success callback), then I can see that I am in fact receiving the expected information.

I have tried tinkering with the json_encode options, adding JSON_HEX_QUOTES, etc. but no success. I have also tried adding information to the SQL table so as not to return any results containing "null". Again, no luck. So I am stuck - because the error only comes up in the webkit console, I can only assume that it is being very particular about the expected JSON format or something, but I don't know. And because I have used a similar process elsewhere in my application without an error, I am having a hard time identifying what makes this instance produce this error.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: As a quick follow-up, I just tried removing the "success: function(a){... etc. }" - which is to say no success callback at all - and the script similarly fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
In most cases your JavaScript is broken in some way. For example missing a } or something like that.

Example given, this will yield "Unexpected end of input" too:

eval('[{"test": 10}') // notice the missing ]
But the root cause of the problems seems to be that the requested JSON url has a Content-Type of text/html which Chrome apparently tries to parse as HTML, which then results in the unexpected end of input due to the fact that the included image tags are being parsed.

Try setting the Content-Type to text/plain I think it should fix the issues.
```

Comment: Thanks Arpita. I have checked the javascript several times and I cannot see anything missing that would cause it to break, and I would expect it to break in other browsers. I did also try to add the following header: header("Content-Type: text/plain");

Comment: Here is the JSON output from the query: [{"num":"35","user":"11199394","title":"Image Title","category":"fashion","date":"1428511556","file":"photo128","type":"jpg","size":"115082","width":"800","height":"590","rank":null,"notes":"Fusce eget felis dui. Sed ullamcorper luctus orci at dapibus. Suspendisse non pretium lacus. Ut a nulla mauris. Vivamus placerat libero in augue elementum dapibus. Donec nec suscipit sem.","comments":null,"score":null,"package":null,"cat-num":"10"}]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if this will be helpful to anyone at all, but perhaps someone might be able to explain this odd quirk. I managed to solve my problem, but I am still not really sure of the cause: basically even though I was able to return valid JSON page to the application from the PHP query, for some reason some "$_SESSION" information was causing something in the JSON to throw a parse error when it came back for use in the javascript callback. When I set the dataType to "text" it was fine, but as soon as I tried "$.parseJSON" it would break the script. Similarly, setting the dataType to "json" would cause it to throw an error, so something in the JSON output was causing the glitch. When I passed the offending session information through the AJAX request instead, as in "data: {foo: 'bar'}", everything worked perfectly - same data, just a different way of getting it there.

What I cannot understand is why only WebKit does not like my method of using session information in this way - this is not a problem at all for IE or Firefox - and why this instance alone worked in this way (and yes, I checked that the session info was not be changed or anything). So I would be interested to know if anyone has encountered such strange behavior before.